# runmqsc AMQ8157: Security Error on MQ Version 8.0.0.5 on Windows 7 x64 Edition

Tags: ibm-mq

Currently, I faced an issue whereby when trying to runmqsc (queue manager name), I achieved an error of AMQ8157: Security Error. Is there any way I can solve this issue?

I am running IBM MQ Version 8.0.0.5 on Windows 7 x64 Edition.

AMQ8157 appeared in the command prompt as `AMQ8157: Security error.`

However, This was the error which was displayed in the error log.

Error Log Message:

```
AMQ8079: Access was denied when attempting to retrieve group membership
information for user 'userdecim@ddgroup.com'.

EXPLANATION:

WebSphere MQ, running with the authority of user 'admin@dd-pc-002',
was unable to retrieve group membership information for the specified user.
ACTION:
Ensure Active Directory access permissions allow user
'admin@dd-pc-002' to read group memberships for user
'userdecim@ddgroup'. To retrieve group membership information for a domain user,
MQ must run with the authority of a domain user and a domain controller must be
available.
```

Comment: @JoshMc Currently Im running MQ on Windows 7 x64 Edition, Version 8.0.0.5

Comment: @JoshMC - The user executing the runmqsc is not in the mqm group. - If I'm not wrong, The MQ running as a domain user.

Comment: @JoshMc I have tried doing that however I still obtain the same error.

Comment: @JoshMc sorry for the late reply, yes I do. 3 files in fact. AMQERR01 - AMQERR03. However AMQERR01 is the only file with data in it. The other error messages are blank.

Comment: I have edited the question to add which version of MQ you are running.  I have also added the information from my comments into my answer and deleted my comments.  Please delete your comments as well since all of the clarification is no contained in the question and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ACTION in the error explains the problem. The IBM MQ queue manager is running as a *local* user `admin` on the host `dd-pc-002`. The queue manager is trying to retrieve group membership information for the *domain* user `userdecim@ddgroup.com`.  Because the queue manager is running under a *local* account it will not have permission to obtain information on a *domain* user.

If the IBM MQ queue manager will interact with *domain* users and groups, the account which the queue manager processes run under on Windows must be a *domain* account that has `Read group membership` and `Read groupMembershipSAM` permissions.

See the IBM MQ v8 Knowledge Center page "[Creating and setting up domain accounts for IBM MQ](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q008840_.htm)" for more details.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I do not have certain permissions, thus waiting for the admins to perform checks on this. However, I do understand the process of it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I was getting a similar error when I was trying to connect to my MQ Server.

The problem was in the MQ service name (eg: `MQ_Installation1` ) in  `services.msc`. By default it had taken my local system account and not my current/domain user account.

After changing this started working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case starting IBM MQ windows service using local account resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without domain account you can run IBM MQ (Installation1) as local user (with start as service rights).
And then you should run MQExplorer as the same local user.
For example local user **mqservice**:

```
runas /u:mqservice /savecred "C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin64\MQExplorer.exe"
```